# How to extract a text from newline followed by some specific keywords in Python?

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I am working on a problem where I have some Multi line strings which are in a table type email snapshot format.

Example below:

```
Hello,

please provide an update on the following invoice

Invoice#        Status    Invoice_Amount        Account#
646464646       Open      7446.00               53334444
645543333       Open      6443.00               23599499
874646553       Open      6223.50               94744663

Thanks,
```

My task is to extract the Invoice numbers which in this case are 646464646,645543333 & 874646553. After looking at few examples I know that they are normally in next line followed by a heading like Invoice# or Invoice Numbers etc.

I my trying to use Regular Expressions to solve this problem but I am not able to build a solution which can match a keyword like "Invoice#" in the header and extract numbers just below that header (*there could be N number of rows in the table snapshot*)

My desired output from this example is:

```
[646464646,645543333,874646553]
```

I tried searching for any existing solution but didn't find any example for a match in newline text, please suggest if you have an idea how to solve this.

Please let me know if further details are required. Thanks.

Edit: The example shown above is not the standard format this is just one of the emails, actual emails may have this snapshot in a different way like there could be more than 4 columns with different headers and names, also the invoice number could have more than or less than 9 digits, only consistent thing I believe is the "Invoice#" keyword in header.

Comment: You asked a very vague question.  Please either show us all email formats or give us a rule for how to identify the invoice number.

Answer (score 1):

Try first splitting your input string/file on `Invoice#`, then use `re.findall` on the second entry in the list:

```
parts = input.split("Invoice#")
numbers = re.findall(r'(\d+)       (?:Open|Closed)', parts[1])
```

If you know for certain that all invoice numbers would always be 9 digits, then you may simplify the matching logic:

```
numbers = re.findall(r'\d{9}', parts[1])
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but this is only one of the examples, different senders write emails in their own formats, also the invoice number is not a fixed 9 digit number, the only possible way is to look text just below the word "Invoice#".

Comment: Well my suggestion should work for the format you actually did show us.  If you have other examples which might alter the solution, then you should have hinted at this in your question.

Comment: Yes, in this case you are right, but the only consistent text in the emails is "Invoice#". There are multiple senders with their own formats, so only possible solution is to extract text just below "Invoice#" text.

Comment: As mentioned this works on the given example only but not for all.

Comment: `but the only consistent text in the emails is "Invoice#"` ... then why wouldn't my approach work for all your email messages?

Comment: As I mentioned, there are multiple scenarios, like it is not necessary that the Status column is there, there could be another column or columns like "P.O.Number" or "Invoice_Date" or may be more or less than. Also the Invoice number might not have 9 digits always.